# add each int in a vector<int> to a string

Tags: c++, char, int

```
for (vector<int>::const_iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
    {
        int number = *i;
        char* c;
        itoa(number, c, 10);
        result += c;
    }
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

I'm trying to convert each int in "vec" to a char and adding it to a string but I just get a compiler error. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, if you are getting a compiler error, why did you decide to not include the error you get, in your question? In addition, `char* c; itoa(number, c, 10);` is undefined behavior anyway due to `c` not being initialized.

Comment: Please include the definition of your variables in your example code. It might have something to do with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) available in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    std::string result;
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
    {
        result += std::to_string(*i);
    }
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please [include](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47941741/edit) `{}` block markers in your `for` statements. Even if it's only one statement inside it.

Comment: I normally do not do it. Is it just for easier interpretation here or is it for general good practice in c++?

Comment: I've added them. Thanks for making my general c++ practice improve.

Comment: @apalomer It is a good practice if you intend to allow people who know no C++ to edit your C++ code.

Comment: the contents of the vector are 0, 6, 11, 17 but the console outputs  #0#6#11#17#0#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9#10#11#12#13#14#15#16#17#18#19#20#21#22#23#24#25#26#27#28#29#30#31#32#33#34#35#36#37#38#39#40#41#42#43#44#45#46#47#48#49#50#51#52#53#54#55#56#57#58#59#60#61#62#63#64#65#66#67#68#69#70#71#72#73#74#75#76#77#78#79#80#81#82#83#84#85#86#87#88#89#90#91#92#93#94#95#96#97#98#99 (i added the # myself to split up each number)

Comment: I would have said `for (auto i : vec) result += std::to_string(i);` in one line.

Comment: @juanchopanza "people who know no C++" should not edit C++ code ... source: I have seen too many terrible things

Comment: @Ron why the `{ in the same line as `for`? I have no reason why it should be either way, but I am used to putting them on a new line because when Qtcreator produces automatic code for you it does it this way.

Comment: @apalomer It's a matter of preference. You can also put it in the new line.

Comment: @HussamAl-hassan the values of my vector are 0..99, no 0,6,11,17. This is why you get this output.

Comment: @Ron performance? you mean my code will run faster if it is in one line?

Comment: @apalomer _Preference_, not _performance_. I've edited the code to your personal preference. My personal preference is to keep the opening brace on the same line.

Comment: how can i change the code so that it results in just the contents of the vector

Comment: @HussamAl-hassan Your question has been answered.

Comment: oh, i see what the problem is. sorry, im still kind of new to c++.

Comment: @ChristianG Exactly. But many coding guidelines seem designed exactly for those people.

Comment: BTW prefer [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) to that site. Much better resource.

Answer (score 1):

Combining sounds like a job for [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

auto main() -> int
{
  const std::vector<int> vec{ 1, 2, 3 };
  const std::string result = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::string(),
    [](const std::string& s, const int value)
    {
      return s + std::to_string(value);
    });

  std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious: what is the benefit of `auto main() -> int` compared to `int main()`?

Comment: No benefit, just a gimmick on my part

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your code:

You call `itoa()` with a non-initialized char pointer. That's bad, because `itoa()` needs a valid buffer! Besides, `itoa()` is not part of the c++ standard.

Better do leave `char*` behind and do it with more modern C++ features, especially [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/?kw=stringstream), which is a string builder, which is powerful in conversion (and also often faster than the string += operator). It builds a string by pushing elements to it with the `<<` operator (these can be string literals, strings, numbers of all kinds), it can be extended via external operators for own data types, and it also has a lot of formatting options (e.g. number of digits, hex etc), and returns its built string with the method `str()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (int i = 0;i<100;i++)
        vec.push_back(i);
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (auto& number : vec)
        ss << number;
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```